# What o-ring can I use for my Omnibasic water filter?

Tags: plumbing, filter

I just bought a house that has an Omnibasic water filter. I don't know when the filter cartridge was last replaced, but it's starting to drip water so I want to replace the cartridge and the o-ring. The cartridges seem to be pretty standard and easy to find, but I'm not sure about the o-ring.

The site recommends their U24 o-ring (http://www.h2owarehouse.com/u24-oring.htm). I could order this from this website, but I'd like to do it soon without waiting for shipping. I'm looking at local hardware stores (Home Depot, Lowes, and Menards) but not seeing this exact model. Does anyone know if this is a standard size, or any other names it might go under?

Comment: I'd bet that it's a standard o-ring but no information about it is given on the reference page.  The usual home centers will likely not have these are they are not common for homeowners.

You might try an industrial supply house like Grainger or McMaster-Carr if one is local to you.  If not, Amazon Supply or ULine might have what you need but you'll need to measure it carefully to get the right size.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom It's not really a "shopping" question. I'm not looking for where to buy it or costs or anything like that. I'm asking a question about standard o-ring sizes. Looking at the tour doesn't really show me how my question is off-topic.